# Are there any android application framework like spring?

Tags: java, android, spring, frameworks, dependency-injection

are there any android application framework like spring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at roboguice:
http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/

BTW, nothing prevents you from use spring - as this is pure java framework. 
but it is heavyweight and probably overkill for your purposes.

Question is - what do you like to inject as dependency?

Comment: The project has moved to another location - https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/

Answer (score 6):

[spring-android](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android) is a fresh spring portfolio project.

Answer (score 6):

Spring framework for Android - [Spring for Android](https://projects.spring.io/spring-android/). Currently it has only a couple of features.

The most used dependency injection frameworks for Android:

- [Butter Knife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)
  refers to itself as "view injection".
- [Dagger 2](https://google.github.io/dagger/)
  new version of Dagger.
  maintained by Google.
- [AndroidAnnotations](http://androidannotations.org/)
  provides the functionality of Dagger + ButterKnife and a bit more in one framework.
- [Transfuse](http://androidtransfuse.org/)
  does not have as large of a community as other DI frameworks, though this does not mean that it is bad.
- [Dagger](https://square.github.io/dagger/) (DEPRECATED)
  deprecated in favor of Google's Dagger 2.
  very powerfull, but it's not intended for views injection.
  can be used together with ButterKnife.
- [RoboGuice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/) (RETIRED)
  it used to be the #1 DI framework on Android.
  easy to plug and play.
  has performance impact.

Choosing the right framework largely depends on your needs.

---

- [Dagger + Butter Knife VS AndroidAnnotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351817)
- [RoboGuice VS Butter Knife](https://dzone.com/articles/dependency-injection-roboguice)
- [Dagger VS ButterKnife](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821148)
- [RoboGuice VS Dagger VS ButterKnife](https://www.quora.com/Which-DI-library-should-I-use-in-Android-development-RoboGuice-Dagger-or-ButterKnife)
- [Transfuse VS Dagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306723)

---

**ps**. A tip from [Managing Your App's Memory](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html#DependencyInjection):

> Avoid dependency injection frameworks.

Though this recommendation does not apply equally to all DI frameworks<sup>[[why?]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24194366/1429387)</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider [Spring ME](http://springframework.me/). Contrary to classic Spring, it is incredibly lightweight. (Where the Spring runtime requires a lot of library code to wire all your beans at compile time, Spring ME is doing all of that at build time, leaving you with a BeanFactory that has *no dependencies on a runtime at all*.)