# DI framework for Android

Tags: android, spring, dependency-injection, roboguice

I am looking for open source Dependency Injection framework for android , After doing some search found that there are multiple frameworks available e.g [RoboSpring](https://github.com/dthommes/RoboSpring),[RoboGuice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice),TinnySpring.
  Can someone please  suggest which option is better one in terms of simplicity and future support?

Comment: older, but some useful info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514674/are-there-any-android-application-framework-like-spring/27464493#27464493

Comment: Did you find anything useful? you can answer your own question if you have.